# PEAR on Apache/PHP 5.3, .phar

Tags: php, pear, phar

Yesterday I managed to install PEAR using SSH on one of my customers servers. Today I tried to install it on a similar Server but without SSH-access.

The manual on pear.php.net claims that:

> If you are running your site at a web
>   hosting provider with no direct access
>   to the server (via local logins,
>   Telnet or SSH), you can use the PEAR
>   Installer using the Web Frontend or
>   (S)FTP.
>
> Go to http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
>   and save as go-pear.phar. Copy
>   go-pear.phar to your server and open
>   the corresponding URL in your browser,
>   for example
>   http://example.com/pear/go-pear.phar.

So I downloaded it, put it in the folder via FTP and... i can see the contents of the file.
I tried downloading it by file_put_contents(file_get_contents()) and again.. nothing but the contents - but no "Installing Interface", which i expected.

So I'm totally new to Archives, especiall the PHP-Archive. But how do I manage to install PEAR without SSH (or Telnet, etc...) only with FTP? How do I "execute" a .phar file in the Browser like the Doc of pear.php.net states?

And furthermore, how do I install packages after installing PEAR? After all.. there is still no command line.

On more thing I tried is to call the archive file:

```
include('phar://go-pear.phar/index.php');
```

However this doesn't get me far. I now can see "Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation. To change individual locations, type the number in front....", which is the standard PEAR installation introduction BUT this is only a **text**. How could I tell a text to change the directory... ? :confused:

**Thanks a lot for your help**. I really searched the docs and google however in both I could not find the answer.

Running: PHP 5.3.2 on Apache/2.2.16

No access to httpd.conf, only .htaccess. It's a shared server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you install PEAR locally and just upload it with the classes you need/want? That's probably the easiest way to do it if you don't have access to the CLI.

See [Installation of a local PEAR copy on a shared host](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php#installation.shared.ftp)

Comment: Hm, i think that's an idea. I will try this, thanks! However I don't see why I can't open the .phar file in the Browser... would be much easier. (Can't I just copy the hole pear installation from an other server, so I would not have to install php locally?)

Comment: Sure, you can FTP it from another server as well if you want.

Comment: Anything to change (execpt include_dir in php_ini)? Like the paths to pear?

Comment: Nope you just set the include_dir to include the folder where you stored PEAR, that's it, nothing else to change. To add classes you just FTP them over in that folder.

Answer (score 3):

You propably forgot to add `.phar` to the list of parsable php files in `httpd.conf`.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phar
```

Comment: I thought of that. But i have no access to httpd.conf.
When I put the line above in a .htaccess file, the go-pear.php seems to be empty - only a blank page.